# Getting invalid cast exception when parsing text boxes

Tags: vb.net

[Error Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/83812754@N07/7759083382/in/photostream)

Well, the link above will show you, but I have some textboxes that, when numbers are inputted, they all automatically sum up and show the sum in a separate box.  Here is my code for the textbox that the sum is displayed at:

```
Try
        Dim One As Integer
        Dim two As Integer
        Dim three As Integer
        Dim four As Integer
        Dim five As Integer
        Dim six As Integer
        Dim seven As Integer
        If CDbl(txtMon1.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtTues1.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtWed1.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtThurs1.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtFri1.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtSat1.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtSun1.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMon1.Text) Then
            One = CInt(0)
            two = CInt(0)
            three = CInt(0)
            four = CInt(0)
            five = CInt(0)
            six = CInt(0)
            seven = CInt(0)
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(txtMon1.Text) Then
            One = CInt(0)
            two = CInt(0)
            three = CInt(0)
            four = CInt(0)
            five = CInt(0)
            six = CInt(0)
            seven = CInt(0)
        Else
            One = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtMon1.Text))
            two = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtTues1.Text))
            three = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtWed1.Text))
            four = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtThurs1.Text))
            five = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtFri1.Text))
            six = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtSat1.Text))
            seven = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtSun1.Text))
            txtTot1.Text = CStr(Math.Round(One + two + three + four + five + six + seven))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub txtTot2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtTot2.TextChanged, txtMon2.TextChanged, txtTues2.TextChanged, txtWed2.TextChanged, txtThurs2.TextChanged, txtFri2.TextChanged, txtSat2.TextChanged, txtSun2.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim One As Integer
        Dim two As Integer
        Dim three As Integer
        Dim four As Integer
        Dim five As Integer
        Dim six As Integer
        Dim seven As Integer
        If CDbl(txtMon2.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtTues2.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtWed2.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtThurs2.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtFri2.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtSat2.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf CDbl(txtSun2.Text) > 24 Then
            MsgBox(Title:="Error", Prompt:="There not more than 24 hours a day.")
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMon2.Text) Then
            One = CInt(0)
            two = CInt(0)
            three = CInt(0)
            four = CInt(0)
            five = CInt(0)
            six = CInt(0)
            seven = CInt(0)
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(txtMon2.Text) Then
            One = CInt(0)
            two = CInt(0)
            three = CInt(0)
            four = CInt(0)
            five = CInt(0)
            six = CInt(0)
            seven = CInt(0)
        Else
            One = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtMon2.Text))
            two = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtTues2.Text))
            three = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtWed2.Text))
            four = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtThurs2.Text))
            five = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtFri2.Text))
            six = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtSat2.Text))
            seven = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtSun2.Text))
            txtTot2.Text = CStr(Math.Round(One + two + three + four + five + six + seven))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using `Integer.TryParse(...)` or `Double.TryParse(...)` for those string conversions to numbers.

Example:

```
Dim One As Integer = 0
If Not Integer.TryParse(txtMon1.Text, One) Then
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry")
End If
```

This line makes little sense:

```
One = CInt(Convert.ToInt64(txtMon2.Text))
```

If you just read it, it says "I am converting to integer converting to integer 64 this string".

Before you can use `CInt(...)` you have to verify the string contents are convertible to a number.  That's where `TryParse(...)` will work for you.

Comment: Hmm, I tried changing the convert.toint64 to integer.tryparse but I'm getting an error saying "overload resolution failed because no accessible 'TryParse' accepts this number of arguments."

Comment: alright, I tried throwing that If statement you provided to the very top of all my if statements.  The error is still happening.  Do I need to change up all my if statements?

Comment: @Shinobi1173 I've looked over your other questions — you seem to be ignoring the help you are getting.  I've found at least 3 answers now that talk about `Integer.TryParse`, but you haven't applied that help to your code yet.  Try making a smaller example work and expand from there.  Debugging code is all about isolating the problem.  As to your question, yes, you have to apply the `TryParse()` to all of your integers that are coming from text boxes.  A NumbericUpDown control might be better suited for your needs that a TextBox.

Comment: I guess it is just my lack of understanding VB.  Too many terms that I do not understand and too many suggestions I have NO IDEA on how to do.  Sorry man, I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the textboxes are null or empty before you check if the values are > 24.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I tried swapping the code around but the error still comes up.  Can you think of anything else?  Also, why do I keep getting negative rep?

Comment: The error in the image says that you are trying to parse an empty string ("") and that obviously doesn't parse.  If you check null or empty first, this shouldn't happen.  You should also check to ensure that the string is numeric in nature.  As another answer mentions, you should be using the TryParse() which will return true or false if it is parseable.

Answer (score 0):

How about something clean and simple like:

```
       Dim hours() As Integer = {txtMon1.Text.Trim.Length, txtTue1.Text.Trim.Length, txtWed1.Text.Trim.Length, txtThurs1.Text.Trim.Length, txtFri1.Text.Trim.Length, txtSat1.Text.Trim.Length, txtSun1.Text.Trim.Length}
    If hours.Min > 0 Then
        Dim hoursval() As Integer = {Convert.ToInt16(txtMon1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtTue1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtWed1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtThurs1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtFri1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtSat1.Text), Convert.ToInt16(txtSun1.Text)}
        If hoursval.Max > 24 Then
            MsgBox("There cannot be more than 24 hours in a day", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        End If
    End If
```

Not tested, but it should work!

I forgot to add - this is in addition to using the tryparse as suggested by others.  The checking for blank string is a common thing users do and this takes care of that without a lot of overhead.